# Gap between rectangles in openGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm developing an app on iOS openGL ES 2.0 platform.

I wrote a simple code that draws several rectangles like tiles.
This code worked perfectly fine on openGL ES 1.x.

Then, I decided to port my code to ES 2.0 and started using shader.
And this gap between rectangles starts to appear.

screenshot 
http://jowall.kr/IMG_0057.PNG

As you can see, they're not white lines but gaps.
Those gaps appear and flicker a lot when I move the objects.

I'm not using any texture on it. Just simple rectangle with 4 vertices and colors in an orthographic view.
Positioning rectangles on the grid is pretty simple and worked fine on ES 1.x, so I'm pretty sure it's correct.

I am wondering if it has something to do with floating-point or sub pixels or ect.. and there's any specific settings I'm missing for ES 2.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using low precision in shaders (lowp)?

Comment: Yes, I have "precision lowp float;" in all my shader code. I also tried "precision mediump float;" instead but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @MaticOblak You're right. "precision highp float;" did fix it! Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest you to read just a bit about those 3 lowp, mediump and highp because all are extremely useful, you just need to know when to use which.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes. I am a newbie to openGL ES2, so there's a lot to catch up in shader language. Thanks a lot.